# Prove $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}; p, q \in \mathbb{Z^+}$: If $a \equiv b \pmod{pq}\space \longrightarrow \space a \equiv b \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

$pq|a-b$ and $p|a-b$

$pql = a-b$ and $pk=a-b$

Let $k=ql$ then,

$pql = pk=a-b$

First, is this correct? Second, if so, why can we let $k=ql$?  How do we know $ql=k$?

Comment: A proof can be given using your calculation. But it needs rewriting. We know that $pq\mid a-b$. We **want to prove** that $p\mid a-b$.

Comment: Ah, so if ql = k then pk=a-b and so p|a-b and a congruent to b mod p.  QED?

Comment: Yes, that's all. Quick, eh? The main point I was making is that we must distinguish between what we know, and what we want to show. Your start "$pq\mid a-b$ and $p\mid a-b$" undermines the logic of the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a \equiv b \pmod {pq}$ if $\exists k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$a=b+pq(k)$$
$$a=b+p(qk) $$
implies $a \equiv b \pmod p$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If $pq$ divides $a-b$, then $p$ divides $a-b$. Then...

---

Alternatively, you set $q\ell=\frac{a-b}{p}$ and $k=\frac{a-b}{p}$, so they must be equal.